# mysql with odbc to ms access - runtime error 3146 (odbc call failed)

Tags: mariadb, runtime-error, odbc

I want to share an intriguing experience I've had along with a solution, although it's not my preferred one. Essentially, we utilize a MYSQL and ODBC connection to MS Access, running a series of demanding queries. Most computers handle these queries seamlessly, except for two, where they throw a RUN-TIME ERROR 3146: ODBC CALL FAILED. These computers are newer, which initially puzzled me. Despite scouring through numerous solutions on Stack Overflow, none seemed to resolve the issue.
Upon comparing the functioning computers with the problematic ones, I discovered a crucial disparity: the MariaDB ODBC driver versions. The working computers were equipped with MariaDB ODBC driver 3.1.17, whereas the newer ones had the latest 3.1.20 installed. Surprisingly, reverting to the older 3.1.17 driver on the new computers resolved the issue entirely.
However, I'm apprehensive about this workaround, as it's merely postponing the inevitable need to upgrade to newer versions. Does anyone have insights into why this discrepancy occurred? Perhaps there are updates required on the server side that could mitigate this issue in the long run? Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you use mysql or mariadb servers? These are two different database products, so using mysql with mariadb connector or vica versa can lead to errors.

Comment: @shadow: He is using MariaDB Connector/ODBC and connects to MS Access.

Comment: @GeorgRichter thanks, but that's not what I asked. Btw the OP connects **from** ms access either to mysql or mariadb

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment thus, adding as answer.

1. If you are using MySQL then user corresponding MySQL ODBC driver.[MySQL ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

To answer your question, you are using two different products which have not promised to be compatible.

> Does anyone have insights into why this discrepancy occurred?

Comment: Yes. While the Maria driver might work, the MySQL driver will work.

Comment: @shadow you have a point --> we use MariaDB 10.3.39; so we use the right ODBC...